# Joining data without having a common ID or same spatial location

Tags: arcmap, attribute-joins

I have two polygon shapefiles, which don't have same spatial locations, neither have common attributes. Is it anyhow possible to join these files in ArcGIS 10.3?

I know the ArcGIS supports two kinds of joining,  with common attribute or with same spatial location. But in this case what I actually need is to generate common feature Id for the two files. Is it possible to generate?

Not in a conventional way, I have generated labels for the polygons then created annotations with them. They brought the desired results for many, but not for all the polygons. They got same new Object IDs but few sequences doesn't match. Can't find the reason.

Comment: If there is no common spatial or attribute value, what exactly do they have in common that relates one feature to another?

Comment: They both have same shapes.  1st data was actually generated by spatially adjusting the 2nd data once. Both have separate information, which are stored within a the same layer. Now the 1st data have been edited so many times, and even errors found in the information which are acquired from the 2nd data.  So it's needed to do the job again. But as it will take same time again, I am looking for an alternative to generate Id for both of them.

Comment: Have you looked at the shape fields, e.g. the perimeter divided by the area or number of vertices some other way to pick up shape similarities?